# Unknown "2X" and "3X" markings on package outline

Tags: datasheet, packages

I was checking the dimensions of a TO-263 transistor on its [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf5305spbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e378101995) (page 8), when I saw something I could not understand. What do markings "2X" (over dimensions *e* and *b*) and "3X" (over dimension *b2*) mean?

[image: package outline]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That just means the particular dimension is repeated that many times somewhere else on the drawing.

For example:

- there are two gaps between pins.
- there are three pin bases
- there are only two pins that actually have a landing on the PCB